# Url to an item with Client Object Model

Tags: development, client-object-model, url

Regarding my question, at this moment i'm writing some client object model code and I can't find a way to retrieve create make an url ...

My question now is: 
How can I create an url to an item? I get an ListItem object with the client object code yes but how to retrieve now an url from it?

If the full url is not possible how can i create a full url to this item?

Thanks for a help.

Update, i have the following code but it is to get the link to document:

```
var objectType = this.listItem.get_fileSystemObjectType();
if(objectType!='invalid'){
var url = this.listItem.get_item('_dlc_DocIdUrl').get_url();
var title = this.listItem.get_item('FileLeafRef');
window.open('mailto:?subject=Emailing%3A%20'+ title + '&body=' + url);
}
// here should come the creation of URL to a list item
else{
....
}
```

Now I have to have link to an item .. and not document, if outside of the library

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether the specified list item belongs to `List` or `Documents library`:

- for `Documents library`: `var absItemUrl = item.get_item('EncodedAbsUrl');`
- for `List` you could return url of display form page

**Example**

```
function getListItemUrl(listTitle,itemId,success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
   ctx.load(item,['EncodedAbsUrl','FileRef']);
   ctx.load(list,['BaseType','DefaultDisplayFormUrl']);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
            var url;
            var baseType = list.get_baseType();
            if(baseType === SP.BaseType.documentLibrary) {
                 url = item.get_item('EncodedAbsUrl'); 
            }
            else {
                 var absSiteUrl = item.get_item('EncodedAbsUrl').replace(item.get_item('FileRef'),''); 
                 url = absSiteUrl + list.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl() + "?ID=" + itemId;
            }   
            success(url);
      },
      error);
}
```

Usage

```
var listTitle = 'Documents';
var itemId = 1;

getListItemUrl(listTitle,itemId, 
   function(url){
       console.log(url);
   },
   function(sendera,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```